# convert to JSON in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a string like this

```
'abc=bbc|xyz=ijk|mno=def'
```

separated by pipe '|' symbol and want to convert it to JSON string in PHP / javascript like this

```
{ "abc": "bbc", "xyz":"ijk", "mno":"def"}
```

I tried javascript replace function but failed. any idea?

Comment: Where do you want to convert it? PHP or JS?

Comment: I prefer PHP. But javascript also no problem.

Comment: In Javascript `var obj = JSON.parse('{' + 'abc=bbc|xyz=ijk|mno=def'.replace(/(\w+)/g, '"$1"').replace(/=/g, ':').replace(/\|/g, ',') + '}');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you can simply use `array_walk` along with `explode` function and finally using `json_encode` as

```
$str = "abc=bbc|xyz=ijk|mno=def";
$arr = [];
array_walk(explode('|',$str),function($v,$k)use(&$arr){ 
      $a = explode("=",$v);
      $arr[$a[0]] = $a[1];
});
echo json_encode($arr);//{ "abc": "bbc", "xyz":"ijk", "mno":"def"}
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/430903)

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you could do:

```js
var input = 'abc=bbc|xyz=ijk|mno=def'
,   resultObj = {};
input
    .split(/\|/g)
    .map(
        function(keyValue){
            var parts = keyValue.split(/\=/g);
            resultObj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
        }
    )
;
var results = '<table><tr><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>';
$.each(resultObj
   ,   function(k, v){
       results += '<tr><td>' + k + '&emsp;&emsp;</td><td>' + v + '</td></tr>';
   }
);
document.write(results + '</table>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider making an object, and using the toJson() method.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tojson.asp 
Just gonna asume you want js

Comment: This wont convert `'abc=bbc|xyz=ijk|mno=def'`  to `{ "abc": "bbc", "xyz":"ijk", "mno":"def"}`

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.